# C using a function without calling its arguments

Tags: c

I am working with some legacy C code, which is quite convoluted. Here is what I have:

In the header file is declared:

```
int derivs(double,const double *,double *,void *);
```

then in the .c file with the same name is another declaration:

```
int derivs(double,const double *,double *,void *);
```

then the function is defined (in the same file):

```
int derivs(double t, const double y[], double dydN[], void * params)
{
     int i;

    if(y[2]>=1.0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<NEQS;i++)
        {
            dydN[i] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(y[2] > VERYSMALLNUM)/*Here for numerical issues in
                        sqrt()*/
        {
            dydN[0]= - sqrt(y[2]/FOURPI); //d phi/ d N eq. (17)
        }
        else
        {
            dydN[0] = 0.0;
        }
        dydN[1] = y[1]*y[2]; // dH / dN = eps * H
        dydN[2] = y[2]*(y[3]+2.0*y[2]); // d epsilon / dN
        dydN[3] = 2.0*y[4]-5.0*y[2]*y[3]-12.0*y[2]*y[2];

        for(i=4;i<NEQS-1;i++)
        {
            dydN[i] = (0.5*(i-3)*y[3]+(i-4)*y[2])*y[i]+y[i+1];
        }
        dydN[NEQS-1] = (0.5*(NEQS-4)*y[3]+(NEQS-5)*y[2])*y[NEQS-1];

    }
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
```

and then in another function in the same file is the following line:

```
z=int_de(y,Nstart,Nend,&kount,kmax,yp,xp,NEQS,derivs);
```

i.e., derivs is called by name only, without any arguments. The function int_de is declared as follows:

```
int int_de (gsl_vector *y, double N, double Nend, int *kount, int kmax,
gsl_matrix *ypp, gsl_vector *xpp, int NEQS, int (*derivs)(double,const
double *, double *,void *))
```

My question is how does the use of `derivs` in `int_de` work? It is called without any of its arguments.

Comment: It's not called, there are no Parentheses. Its passed.

Comment: The declaration doesn't need the argument names, only their type.

Comment: It's passing a pointer to the function. See the function definition (`int derivs(double,const double *,double *,void *);`) and the way it's passed in `int_de` (`int (*derivs)(double, const double *, double *, void *)`.

Comment: @tkausl okay could you please explain this? What is the purpose of passing a function?

Comment: It is passed as a function pointer. You see the declaration for `int int_de (...int (*derivs)(double,const double *, double *,void *))` declares the type of function pointer it expects.

Comment: Why does a function need to be passed after it is already defined? Can't it just be called inside the body of the other function?

Comment: The purpose of passing a function pointer is that you can pass a different function that returns the same type and accepts the same argument types, which means you can use many different functions in the call to `int_de` when you need different behavior.

Comment: The purpose of passing a function is it allows you to pass another function name and change the behavior within the function where it is used. (I give, @KenWhite is just faster `:)`

Comment: Take a look at [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that the function `derivs` isn't being called yet - its *address* is being passed to `int_de`, which will probably call `derivs` using its address later. See for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/

An example of how this could be useful. In the following code, we re-use the logic in the function `accumulate` to get either the `sum` or the `product` of a list of ints, depending on which of `add` and `multiply` we pass in. This way, we don't have to write out the looping logic twice, which should help protect us against any copy-paste errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}

// We can pass any function with matching signature in as binary_operation, and
// accumulate will use it!
int accumulate(int starting_value, int length, int* values, int binary_operation(int, int))
{
    int result = starting_value;
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        result = binary_operation(result, values[index]);
    }
    return result;
}

int sum(int length, int* values)
{
    return accumulate(0, length, values, add);
}

int product(int length, int* values)
{
    return accumulate(1, length, values, multiply);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int values[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    printf("sum of first three = %d\n", sum(3, values));
    printf("product of all five = %d\n", product(5, values));
}
```

Compiling and running this, I get the output:

```
sum of first three = 6
product of all five = 120
```